# Adding AM_LDFLAGS has no effect in final library, causing linker errors

Tags: c++, linux, autotools, autoconf, automake

I'm using GNU autohell for my project which is a C++ library. It should link against ZMQ and boost. So I added this check for needed libraries in `configure.ac`

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(ZMQ, libzmq >= 3.2.3)
```

and linker flags in `Makefile.am`:

```
AM_LDFLAGS = -lzmq
```

Everything compiles and links but I got undefined reference errors when try to use library in a real application. I wondered if it really links against necessary libs or not. Surprisingly, result of `ldd` is like this:

```
ldd ./libait-0.1.0.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff85dfd000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fea7efa4000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fea7ebe5000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fea7e9ce000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fea7e6d2000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fea7f4d9000)
```

There is no link to ZMQ nor other libraries added like this. What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

Contents of `Makefile.am`

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = subdir-objects
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = ${ACLOCAL_FLAGS} -I m4
#AM_LDFLAGS = -lzmq
libait_la_LIBADD = $(ZMQ_LIBS)
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libait-@AIT_API_VERSION@.la
AM_CPPFLAGS = -pipe
libait_@AIT_API_VERSION@_la_SOURCES = ....
libait_@AIT_API_VERSION@_la_LDFLAGS = -version-info $(AIT_SO_VERSION)
ait_includedir = $(includedir)/ait
ait_include_HEADERS =  ....
ait_libincludedir = $(libdir)/ait-$(AIT_API_VERSION)/include
pkgconfigdir = $(libdir)/pkgconfig
pkgconfig_DATA = ait-$(AIT_API_VERSION).pc
dist_noinst_SCRIPTS = autogen.sh
```

Comment: So what's wrong, concretely?  The output of `ldd` looks OK so far.

Comment: @ldav1s shouldn't there be links to `libzmq` and boost?

Comment: there should be links to those libs if they are _used_.  With Boost, there may or may not be libraries, depending on what you are using from Boost.  Lots of Boost doesn't depend on an external lib besides `libstdc++`.

Comment: @ldav1s serialization and filesystem from boost are used and ZMQ is used. Though I can't see any sign of linkage in final binary artifacts. Also there is no `-lzmq` or `-lboost_filesystem` in compile/link stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PKG_CHECK_MODULES(ZMQ, libzmq >= 3.2.3)` sets the variables: `ZMQ_CFLAGS` and `ZMQ_LIBS`.

Use `AC_SUBST(ZMQ_LIBS)` in `configure.ac` for the `Makefile.am` substitution variable:
`libait_la_LIBADD = $(ZMQ_LIBS)`

This approach lets `libtool` handle the library dependencies, and maintain dependency information in the `libait.la` file.

Comment: It says "variable `libait_la_LIBADD' is defined but no program or library has `libait_la' as canonical name (possible typo)" I edited my question and put complete `Makefile.am`

Comment: That’s because your library has the name `libait-0.1.0`; which probably isn’t the right way to do this … But if you insist, just do it like the `_SOURCES` and `_LDFLAGS` three lines below.